# Wiring a ceiling rose - one switch turns off everything else

Tags: wiring, lighting

I'll try and get a picture soon but here's my issue.
My house is old, it was built in the late 70s/early 80s so has some questionable wiring.

In my upstairs, I have 3 bedrooms, a landing light, a bathroom mirror light and a switch that controls the attic light. The landing light switch is a two-way one that I can switch on and off from either upstairs or downstairs.

The issue I have is..

The hall light does not work at all.

The light in one bedroom needed a replacement light fitting. I have a ceiling rose. Coming out of my ceiling I have 4 wires. All of them are grey. If i look i can see inner sleeves, 3 red and one blue.
If I turn the hall light switch on, I get a permanent live. I can identify the switched live (i tested if power was going in when the room switch was on/off).

I originally wired the switch live to the fitting live (brown) and the blue wire to the blue screw in the fitting. The other two wires I put in the middle.

When I switched on the bedroom light, all of the other lights upstairs no longer work. When i turn it off, they the other bedroom and bathroom lights work. The landing, attic and bathroom mirror lights don't work.

I was told I should also wire the 'permanent' live to the switched live; I tried that and this made the landing and bathroom mirror light work. But, as soon as I switch the bedroom light on - all the upstairs lights go off.

I'm clearly overlooking something here but I cannot figure out what it is.

The light switch in the bedroom has a loose fitting, so it looks like it was tampered with at some point but I'm not sure if the problem is in the switch. I was able to get it off and basically there's always power coming in from the bottom wire and the switch just switched between the two top wires.

Any ideas gladly welcomed!

Here's a terrible diagram

[image]

Comment: Here's a terrible diagram..

Comment: Late 70's to early 80's (assuming you're talking about 1970s - 1980s and not the 1800s), certainly is not old in many areas, and if done to code, is usually pretty close to modern electrical codes.  So just considering the wiring questionable only based on age of the house is probably not a concern in and of itself.

Comment: If the hall switch is affecting everything, then the error is in the rose above the lamp that switch is supposed to be controlling. I can only guess someone has switched the permanent live rather than running it parallel. Photos of the back of that switch & the ceiling rose of its corresponding lamp may help.

Comment: House close to mine was built in 1690 - so you think your house is "old"...

Comment: Tetsujin - thank you for your constructive answer. I thought that as well but the off thing is, that light (the landing light) only has two wires coming out of the ceiling.

One thing that might be worth mentioning is that the house was remodelled a few years ago and the bathroom mirror light and attic light were new additions to the existing wiring. And one thing I neglected to mention is there is also a light in the airing cupboard with a switch that controls the attic light as well (which currently doesn't work)

Comment: That's at least part of the problem. Even if it's the only lamp on the circuit, it has to have 4 wires [plus earth, which we've kind been ignoring for now]. 2 in from the mains & 2 out to the switch & back. [If it's part of a proper ring it has 6 - 2 in, 2 switch, 2 onwards] I'd be tempted to call a sparky, get it looked at properly. That is a very clear indication whoever last messed with the cabling had no clue whatsoever. I would let a trained professional look at it, rather than guess & make things go bang.

Comment: That was why I said "questionable wiring" but some people thought that making disparaging comments about age instead of offering something useful was necessery..
I think you're right, I'll need a Sparky - if I had to guess, I'd say whoever installed the bathroom  mirror and attic lights, somehow 're-routed' the wiring out towards them. Come to think of it, I don't remember the landing light ever working... :/